# Making own server and hosting a website

Tags: smtp, server, host

So I came up with idea of creating website and putting it on my server that will be made out of old pc (I am planning on installing ubuntu there and start running own server). The question is , can i setup my server to work with SMTP and at the same time host my website that is going to work with it? And another one , if I coded a website is it necessary buy domain name? or is there a way to put website online for free ???

Comment: You can make an SMTP server that is also a web server. You don't have to buy a domain name for others to see your site. You just need to give them your external IP and make sure your router accepts incoming connections.

Please look these questions up individually on the site. Most likely, this will get downvoted into oblivion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh Alex,

I feel for you. There are a lot of questions in that post. First you need to make sure that you are able to run a server on your ISP. Some ISP's have clauses in their contracts that forbid you from doing this. This is not to say that you can't do it, but be aware that there might be ramifications to doing this against contract. You can setup your server with UBUNTU to run a mail server and a web server. Yes this is certainly possible.

It is not necessary to buy a domain name. Domain Names are merely there to redirect everyone in a clean way to your IP address. Usually this is a static IP. You can lease them from your ISP sometimes. Though as stated above they frown upon using it for server purposes. You can direct your web server to display your website at a specific port such as the default port 80. so for instance you would have an IP address 192.168.1.1:80 that you could give out to your friends and also access yourself. So no it is not necessary to buy a domain name up front.

I would suggest, if you can, to lease a droplet from DigitalOcean.com That way you don't have to support your own hardware. The lowest one costs $5 and it's decent to use as a dev server. If you run into problems it's just a matter of deleting the droplet and spinning up a new one. Instead of completely re-installing Ubuntu from scratch every time. I hope you get this figured out!

To install a web server such as Apache you can start with this tutorial.

[Install a LAMP Stack on UBUNTU](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu)

[Install a Mail Server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-mysql-and-spamassassin)

to get your computers IP use the command below at a terminal prompt. Usually there is an eth1 designator that will show an inet addr: 192.168.1.1 your IP address will be different.

```
ifconfig
```